# Executing thread groups separately in jmeter

Tags: multithreading, testing, automated-tests, jmeter

I have 2 thread groups in my test case. Group A should complete first before Group B starts to execute(at least I though this was the way it worked).

Unfortunately they are firing at the same time and tests from both tread groups are executing, what can I do to prevent this from happening. Not to allow group B to start before group A is done executing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to the test plan element and check the box "Run Thread Groups consecutively".  This will give you what you want.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan

Comment: excellent thanks, may I ask, since I consider Jmeter documentation to be very poor, where did you get the most info about using Jmeter?

Comment: I agree that the documentation is a bit lacking.  I get *most* of my info from trial and error combined with the user manual combined with google searches that generally point me to the JMeter mailing list.

Comment: Mailing List Archives: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jakarta-jmeter-user/

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me although it makes perfect sense that it should.